# How can I check an array for an object before its been added?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

Problem is, I make an empty array and it stays empty until a user is on my page and inputs their "username" and their "ID" and clicks a button.

I have to check the array for duplicates so I want my code to check the array, if nothing with the same name exists then add it into the array. Here is my code that does not work

```
var myArray = []; 

function arrayChecker(inputName, inputID) {
    for (var key in myArray) {
        if (myArray.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log(key, myArray[key]);
        } else {
            myArray.push({"name": inputName, "id": inputID});           
        }
    }  
}
```

This does not work however. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you checking for keys in the array?  You should be checking your object's keys.

Comment: So it's an array of objects? Why not just do an object with a key value pair. inputName: inputID

Comment: why to reinvent wheel ? You could use lodash  `lodash.unionBy`

Comment: @Take_Care_ for this scenario it's unnecessary to import lodash when JS has built-in functions for doing that.  For example, the function `some` solves that problem.

Answer (score 0):

A better implementation:

```
function arrayChecker(inputName, inputID) {
    if (!myArray.some(x => x.name === inputName && x.id == inputID)) {
      myArray.push({"name": inputName, "id": inputID});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not check for duplicates. the `myArray.hasOwnProperty(key)` part only checks if the index (key) is in the array. however, you mostly want to check if the object on index=key has `name==inputName` and `id==inputID`. so your code needs to look something like that:

```
var myArray = []; 

function arrayChecker(inputName, inputID) {

    var check=false;

    for (var key in myArray) {
        if (myArray.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (myArray[key].name == inputName && myArray[key].id == inputID)
                check=true;
        }  
    }

    if (!check)
        myArray.push({"name": inputName, "id": inputID});
}
```

Comment: I tried that but nothing runs past the for statement. Is it because my array is initially empty?

Comment: yes you are right. i edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = []; 

function arrayChecker(inputName, inputID) {
    if (!myArray.find(user=>user.name===inputName)){ // you can also check the id if necessarr
       myArray.push({"name": inputName, "id": inputID});          
    } else {
       console.log('user already exists')
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Miguel thanks for the answer. I am getting an "Unexpected token >" on the line that has the if statement in my IDE program I am using. I am not sure if it is me or an error in the code? Any ideas?

Comment: you probably are running a version of node that doesnt accept arrow functions...

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is a `for-of-loop` and check for the specific values:

**Old fashion way:**

```
function arrayChecker(inputName, inputID) {
    for (var obj of myArray) {
        if (obj.name === inputName && obj.id === inputID) {
            return false;
        }
    }  

    myArray.push({"name": inputName, "id": inputID});

    return true;
}
```

**Using function `some`:**

```
function arrayChecker(inputName, inputID) {
    var found = myArray.some(function (obj) {
        return obj.name === inputName && obj.id === inputID
    });

    if (found) return false;

    myArray.push({"name": inputName, "id": inputID});

    return true;
}
```

**Important:** The function `arrayChecker` returns the result for checking purposes, i.e: If the object was added or not.  `true` was added and `false` wasn't added.

Comment: This it the best one by far, thank you. When I try the code it seems that if I try and compare with an object that was pushed to it by the myArray.push statement below it is not able to correctly compare and found always returns false. However, if I make the object in the code such as                                                                                                     myArray.push({"name": "phillip, "id": "123"}) then the script will correctly compare the name and ID and identify if it existed already. This means it is something with my parameters/inputs?